# the request.get(url) returns only header information with the body empty

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I try to scraping page that does not need to do sign in with this code

```
page_pro = requests.get('url')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page_pro.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup2)
```

the return of this request gave me all the header information but give me only this information for the body

```
<body class="js-active" ng-cloak="">
<div autoscroll="true" ui-view=""></div>
</body>
```

how can I resolve this problem

Comment: this a dynamically generated website

Comment: give us the link

Comment: https://ec.europa.eu/eures/eures-searchengine/page/main?lang=it#/search